# android backward compatability error- java.lang.NoSuchMethod error

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, android-sdk-2.3

I want to provide backward compatability to android 2.2 versions.I have two classes(NoteList.java & NoteEdit.java) and its main components are Navigation drawer and Actionbar. The app is running well on android 4.2 & above versions but it crashes(force closes) on android 2.2..I've tried changing minsdkversion in manifest file and also tried adding support libraries(android.support.v7.appcompat) to libs folder and added to build path, but the app keeps on crashing.

> **NoteList.java**

package com.example.notepad;

```
import android.app.ActionBar;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class NoteList extends Activity 
{
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ListView mainList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.notelist);
      mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets);
      mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
      mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
      final Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale);
      mainList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);       
      mainList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mPlanetTitles));
      ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
      actionBar.show();

      mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override 
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, final int position, long id) {
              anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                  @Override 
                  public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { 

                  }
                  @Override 
                  public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                  } 
                  @Override 
                  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                      view.startAnimation(anim);
                      } 
                  }); 
      view.startAnimation(anim); 
      } 
   }); 

      mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));

      actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,                 
              mDrawerLayout,         
              R.drawable.ic_launcher, 
              R.string.drawer_open, 
              R.string.drawer_close 
              );
      mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
      getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
  }

  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.menus, menu);
      return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

      if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
          return true;
      }
      switch(item.getItemId())
      {
      case R.id.new_note: 
                        Intent intent = new Intent(NoteList.this,NoteEdit.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

      default: 
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }

  }

}
```

> **Manifest file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.notepad"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >

        <activity android:name=".NoteList"
             android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>            
       </activity>

       <activity android:name=".NoteEdit"
             android:label="@string/app_name">           
       </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

> **Error Log**

```
06-06 07:44:15.508: E/AndroidRuntime(339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 07:44:15.508: E/AndroidRuntime(339): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.notepad.NoteList.getActionBar
06-06 07:44:15.508: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at com.example.notepad.NoteList.onCreate(NoteList.java:39)
06-06 07:44:15.508: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-06 07:44:15.508: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-06 07:44:15.508: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-06 07:44:15.508: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-06 07:44:15.508: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-06 07:44:15.508: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-06 07:44:15.508: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-06 07:44:15.508: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-06 07:44:15.508: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 07:44:15.508: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-06 07:44:15.508: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-06 07:44:15.508: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-06 07:44:15.508: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

> **notelist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/notelist"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="214dp"
        android:layout_height="322dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>   

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar() for android api < 11.

Quoting the doc
"
Removing the action bar

You can hide the action bar at runtime by calling hide(). For example:

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();

On API level 11 or higher
Get the ActionBar with the getActionBar() method.

"

Comment: I've tried using getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar(). Even then the app crashes. "error in binary xml file-failed to inflate(LayoutInflater)

Answer (score 0):

create a actionbar object and use it instead of getActionBar and getSupportActionBar..

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Also add appCompat V7 library to your project and import it.